# BinaryOperator doesn't work when comes to a=function(b,c)?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I want to identify the Expression like *`int a = function(b,c)`*， so I wrote the code as followers:

```
void foo(int* a, int *b) {
int x;
int m;
int z;
int *p;
  if (a[0] > 1) {
    b[0] = 2;
    z=10;
    x = function( sizeof(char));
  }
  m = function( sizeof(char));
   bar(x,m);
}

void bar(float x, float y);

int function(int size){
    return size;
}
```

And than I used `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only cfunc_with_if.c` to get the AST of the code:
[image]

From the result I found the AST Node type of *`int a = function(b,c)`* is **BinaryOperator**. In order to verify this, I use `VisitStmt(Stmt *s)` to print out all stmts' type.

```
bool VisitStmt(Stmt *s) {
    if(isa<Stmt>(s)) {
        Stmt *Statement = dyn_cast<Stmt>(s);
    //Statement->dump();
    std::string st(Statement->getStmtClassName());
    st = st + "\n";
    TheRewriter.InsertText(Statement->getLocStart(), st, true, true);
    }
  return true;
  }
```

But the result is so weird. There is **nothing printed out** about the type of *`int a = function(b,c)`*. and I'm so confused about the result. Is there some error in my code or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no output at `bar(x,m);` either. Are there any errors when the tool compiles the code being analyzed? As written above, the code would fail to compile at `x = function( sizeof(char));` since `function` has not been declared. Even when compilation has failed due to errors, the libtool tools can still run at least partially, with strange results.

Edit to add: what happens if you run the tool on this code?

```
void bar(float x, float y);

int function(int size);

void foo(int* a, int *b) {
int x;
int m;
int z;
int *p;
  if (a[0] > 1) {
    b[0] = 2;
    z=10;
    x = function( sizeof(char));
  }
  m = function( sizeof(char));
   bar(x,m);
}

void bar(float x, float y);

int function(int size){
    return size;
}
```

Comment: In fact I don't know about the code, but when I used the code in this [link](http://jszhujun2010.farbox.com/post/llvm&clang/clang-tutorial-di-er-bu-fen#toc_6) I can get the name of every CallExpr